# How to add a xml view to a linear layout programatically

Tags: android, xml

This is working if the view is created programatically like this

```
EditText et = new EditText(getContext());
LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(getContext());
lL.addView(et);
```

but when I created EditText from xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:clickable="true">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and add it this way :

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(getContext());
lL.addView(et);
```

the result is app force close
Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: If you create the view directly in xml there's no need of _LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(getContext());
lL.addView(et);_

Comment: oh I see. if it is so, how and can I possibly move editText to in front of things drawn on canvas? P.s.all of the code is in custom surfaceview class

Comment: This is another question. Please make a new one

Comment: thanks. I've created a new one. please check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064257/how-to-make-xml-object-show-up-in-front-of-drawn-objects-in-canvas