# How to make xml object show up in front of drawn objects in canvas

Tags: android, xml, canvas

I created an EditText from xml and many things drawn on canvas. How to make EditText to be in front of the other objects drawn on canvas?

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:clickable="true">

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I set this on a custom SurfaceView class

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this); //Canvas is instatiated inside thread class
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    //draw things
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}
```

Main Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Set fullscreen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new GamePanel(this)); //GamePanel is the custom SurfaceView class

}
```

edit_text.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="Hello World">
</EditText>
```

The current code shows no EditText object. I do not know whether it is still under the canvas or not shown at all. Any idea and explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you use your SurfaceView class? I'd like to see how did you add it to the UI (in xml or in code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see where you add your `EditText` to your `SurfaceView`. So if you want just add only `EditText` without any parent (I mean `RelativeLayout` in your xml), then you need to create xml containing only `EditText`, called for example `edit_text.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="Hello World" />
```

And then you should inflate it and add to your `GamePanel`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Set fullscreen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
    EditText editText = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text, null);
    gamePanel.addView(editText);

    setContentView(gamePanel); //GamePanel is the custom SurfaceView class

}
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to cast inflated view to `EditText`, so it should look like `EditText editText = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text, null);`

**EDIT 2:**

To resolve the error that `SurfaceView` doesn't have `addView` method you can create a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` instead, and add there your `SurfaceView` and `EditText`:

```
    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    gamePanel.setLayoutParams(gameParams);

    RelativeLayout content = new RelativeLayout(this);
    EditText editText = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text, null);

    content.addView(gamePanel);
    content.addView(editText);

    setContentView(content);
```

Comment: it says incompatible types on EditText editText. Required : android.widget.EditText. Found : android.view.View. and also cannot resolve method on gamePanel.addView. By the way please check my edited post if I have created edit_text.xml the right way, maybe I am missing something

Comment: still get cannot resolve method on gamePanel.addView(editText). I think SurfaceView does not have that method?

Comment: wow it works somehow! Thanks a lot! just one more question. since we created editText in mainactivity. how can I access editText in GamePanel class? for example, in GamePanel class, getting the text from editText and also setting its visibility too. should I use setter and getter or is there easier way to do so?

Comment: You can keep a reference for EditText in your GamePanel, and install that reference by getter and setter, right. The other way to do it, is to call `EditText editText = (EditText) getParent().getChildAt(1)` method, but this method will only work if you have `EditText` added as a second view of your `RelativeLayout`. You also can accept my answer, if it was helpful for you:)

Comment: Accepted. But I still wonder how to pass it. I got cannot resolve method getChildAt(); And I just realized I that I cannot create global variable on mainactivity right therefore I cannot create setter and getter I assume?

Comment: cast it to `ViewGroup`. `ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();`

Comment: @rom4ek hello here what is GamePanel?
can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the `EditText` after the canvas instance, therefore avoid initializating a View in the `SurfaceCreated` method of SurfaceHolder.Callback, because this will cause always to have all its declarated content in the background before onDraw it's called;

simply try this

```
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
           // nice part to start all the background independiently to onDraw for example
        Canvas canvas;
    canvas.drawRGB(255,255,255);

    // you will see that a white background will be drawed before all what you can put in onDraw class

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        //draw things
     EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
// here is where you can initializate the editText

    }
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but there is no change. Canvas is instatiated in my custom thread class so I assume it is the same as instatiating canvas in surface created right? (see my edited post)